# Woocommerce one page checkout custom

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

I want to use one page checkout process in woocommerce. i have created a new page(addition) with some name and have added the shortcode
[woocommerce_cart][woocommerce_checkout]
here is the shortcodes i am using
[image]
It is working fine but login for returning customer login button is not working.
but on checkout page returning customer login button is working.
Can you please help?
i want to make one page checkout process. Image is attached Please help 
[image: Here is the Image For returning customer]

Comment: There's also [One Page Checkout](https://woocommerce.com/products/woocommerce-one-page-checkout/) which will save you hours of coding.

Comment: I have bought the plugin but increment + decrement - buttons are missing on checkout page below billing address section.

Comment: At start buttons appear but after completion loading the buttons disappear.

Comment: If you have bought the plugin then you should contact their support. The ProsPress team is very sharp. Though the first thing they will ask you is to test if it's your theme by seeing if it works with a default theme such as Twenty Seventeen. 80% of the time, the problem is your theme.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to the woocommerce settings (checkout tab) and set both cart page and checkout page to your single-checkout page